# Using asyncio with Azure Computer Vision SDK read_in_stream

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, ocr, python-asyncio, azure-cognitive-services

I have an application where I need to process several pdfs using Azure Computer Vision SDK. I am following [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/blob/d6112cf0411fd3a7fadda3d0603ebd1b02146cbb/python/ComputerVision/ExtractTextPDF.py#L48) example from the official documentation.

From what I have understood, we can submit pdfs by

```
# Async SDK call that "reads" the image
response = client.read_in_stream(filepath, raw=False)
```

and get the results using `operation_location`

```
# Get ID from returned headers
operation_location = response.headers["Operation-Location"]
operation_id = operation_location.split("/")[-1]

# SDK call that gets what is read
while True:
    result = client.get_read_result(operation_id)
    if result.status.lower () not in ['notstarted', 'running']:
        break
    print ('Waiting for result...')
    time.sleep(10)
return result
```

I have noticed that `read_in_stream` takes around 10 to 30 seconds (depending on number of pages, images in pdf, quality, etc.) and would like to use `asyncio` to concurrently proceed to next tasks instead of waiting for pdfs to just submit. I tried using `joblib` backends to speed this up (multithreading, multiprocessing and also a combination of the two), but the performance was just 2-2.5 times better even after tweaking other parameters of `joblib`.

I want to know the correct way of using `asyncio` for this problem and would like to keep using the azure SDK objects instead of resorting to requests library and dealing with raw json responses. I think with `requests`, `asyncio` and `aiohttp` library this could be achieved as below, but how to proceed with azure SDK?

```
timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total = 3600)
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout = timeout) as session:
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        # Submit pdfs and get its result
```